# How to serialze the correct fields that are stored on has a has_many through relation table

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I have a has_many through relationship. But I need to serialize a field stored on the relation table as workflow_state.

To do this I have to access the relation table directly.

Here is the current serializer I have:

```
class OrderSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  
  attributes :id, :number, :slug, :quoted, :invoiced, :paid, :reciepted, :void, :refund, :workflow_state
  has_one :table
  has_one :user
  has_one :quote
  has_one :reciept
  has_many :items

  class RecieptSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    attributes :id, :order_number, :number, :slug, :cost, :paid, :vat, :total, :change
  end
  
  class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    attributes :id, :name, :email
  end

  class QuoteSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    attributes :id, :order_number, :number, :slug, :cost, :vat, :total
  end

  class TableSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    attributes :id, :number, :position
  end
  
  def items
    customized_items = []

    object.items.each do |item|
      # Assign object attributes (returns a hash)
      # ===========================================================
      custom_item = item.attributes
      # has_one w/only specified attributes
      custom_item[:category] = item.category.slice(:id, :name, :icon)
      custom_item[:workflow_state] = item.order_items.find_by_item_id(item.id).workflow_state
      customized_items.push(custom_item)
    end
    
    return customized_items
  end
end
```

The issue is it gives the correct type of response however the field it shows is wrong says 'created' for all items. But when I check the database, the field is "preparing".

Response:

```
{
    "order": {
        "id": 7,
        "number": 7,
        "slug": "61b8a5ad-b3f9-4492-b7d7-2c61684c4988",
        "quoted": true,
        "invoiced": false,
        "paid": false,
        "reciepted": false,
        "void": false,
        "refund": false,
        "workflow_state": "preparing",
        "table": {
            "id": 9,
            "number": 9,
            "position": "Bar"
        },
        "user": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "admin",
            "email": "admin@admin.com"
        },
        "quote": {
            "id": 7,
            "order_number": 7,
            "number": 7,
            "slug": "43f0ca98-84dc-4e6d-8062-f3f1ef1f2e5f",
            "cost": "22.0",
            "vat": "0.0",
            "total": "22.0"
        },
        "reciept": null,
        "items": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Eggs bendict",
                "icon": "breakfast",
                "cost": "5.5",
                "price": "7.5",
                "description": "Eggs on toasted muffins with holindais sauce",
                "category_id": 1,
                "organisation_id": 1,
                "created_at": "2020-06-26T07:45:44.603Z",
                "updated_at": "2020-06-26T07:45:44.603Z",
                "category": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Breakfast",
                    "icon": "breakfast"
                },
                "workflow_state": "created"
            },
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Eggs bendict",
                "icon": "breakfast",
                "cost": "5.5",
                "price": "7.5",
                "description": "Eggs on toasted muffins with holindais sauce",
                "category_id": 1,
                "organisation_id": 1,
                "created_at": "2020-06-26T07:45:44.603Z",
                "updated_at": "2020-06-26T07:45:44.603Z",
                "category": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Breakfast",
                    "icon": "breakfast"
                },
                "workflow_state": "created"
            },
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Eggs bendict",
                "icon": "breakfast",
                "cost": "5.5",
                "price": "7.5",
                "description": "Eggs on toasted muffins with holindais sauce",
                "category_id": 1,
                "organisation_id": 1,
                "created_at": "2020-06-26T07:45:44.603Z",
                "updated_at": "2020-06-26T07:45:44.603Z",
                "category": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Breakfast",
                    "icon": "breakfast"
                },
                "workflow_state": "created"
            },
            {
                "id": 13,
                "name": "Fries",
                "icon": "fries",
                "cost": "5.5",
                "price": "7.5",
                "description": "Fries",
                "category_id": 5,
                "organisation_id": 1,
                "created_at": "2020-06-26T07:45:44.636Z",
                "updated_at": "2020-06-26T07:45:44.636Z",
                "category": {
                    "id": 5,
                    "name": "Sides",
                    "icon": "fries"
                },
                "workflow_state": "created"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

What I'm thinking is this:

```
custom_item[:workflow_state] = item.order_items.find_by_item_id(item.id).workflow_state
```

Its probably serializing the first item that in order_items with item id as specified.

Is there a better way to serialise a field from the relation table for a given relation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I refactored the whole app to not use a has_many :through relationship.